# Disabling lots and lots of NFS mounts based on location

Tags: macos, nfs

I have a number of NFS automounts in my Local directory node on 10.7. I am using a laptop and when I work at home I don't have access to the servers. As a result I often get beachballing Navigation Services dialogs for example, and logs are flooded with NFS error messages on this and that server not being reachable.

Is there some simple app (preferably a GUI one but scripting will do as well) which will disable the mounts when I am on WiFi or just not at work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this is not easily done. To disable automounts you need to actually remove them from the directory services. What I think I will try is just mounting the requisite volumes manually with the `mount` command when I am at work and unmounting them once I am home. This way no apps will get hung up on files that cannot be opened.

However it's a pity that `automountd` is so badly designed that it does not allow disabling or enabling mounts and does not have a hard limit on retires on a mount when the network configuration is stable.

Answer (score 1):

Try [ControlPlane](http://www.controlplaneapp.com/feature-list/). It can perform all sorts of different actions, including mounting/unmounting network drives based on various triggers, including which WiFi network you're connected to.